# Image inside html.textboxfor

Tags: html, css

I am enhancing the design of my project and I want to add a watermark in my `@html.textboxfor`. I was able to add it but it's not working on IE 8. So, I would like to add an image inside my `@html.textboxfor` for the user to know what should be given or typed inside the `textbox` even if the watermark will not work.

The problem is I can't make it work. I tried CSS I searched from the web but none of it is working.

Here is an example of how it looks. Thanks in advance.
[image: example]

Comment: what icons? you mean the X and the eye? It's browser specific and you shouldn't change it.

Comment: @Joraid: I want to add something like that. Please ignore the comment on the image. I just used that for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish that.

**1- is to give the illusion of having an image in an input text field.**

**2- way is to have a background for the input field.**

**Method 1:**

Take this example:

<kbd>[JS-FIDDLE-DMEO](http://jsfiddle.net/N9Q3q/2/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div class="some-input-parent" style="border: 1px solid #DDD;">
   
      <input class="some-input" style="border: none; "/>   
      <img class="some-input-img"  src="yourImage.png"/>   

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.some-input{
width:120px;
}
.some-input-img{
width:15px;
}

.some-input-parent{
  width:140px;
 }
```

The trick is to have a `div` or a `span` that contains an input field, and that `div` will have the image as well aligned either to the right or left (*based on your need*).

The width of the span will equal the width of the text field + the width of the image + some extra space for the borders, padding, etc.

---

---

**Method 2:**

Once you set the background, push it to the right by specifying it's position. Then add padding to the input field to give it an outer width so that we prevent the text from overlapping with the image.

<kbd>[JS-FIDDLE-DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/N9Q3q/3/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<input class="real-input" type="text" />
```

**CSS:**

```
.real-input
{
    background-image: url(youIcon.png");
    background-position: 119px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 17px auto;
    padding-right: 26px;
    width: 111px;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it possible to put it inside the textbox?

Comment: Yup, it's possible. Kindly check my update and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I was about to tell you that most likely you will need to use **-ms-filter** or **DXImageTransform**, but since you already solve it, then that's great.

Comment: So to let others know that this answer is working fine, kindly march the green check below the voting buttons to indicate this as a correct answer. Cheers.